# Excel array formula does not work when using logical operators

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to count the number of rows matching various conditions, so I am using an array formula of the form

```
=SUM(IF(...,1,0))
```

To start building it, I first count the number of records I have to further consider:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(A:A),1,0))
```

And I get the result I expect (some nonzero value). So next I start filling in all my logic, and its behavior makes no sense to me. For example:

```
=SUM(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A:A),TRUE()),1,0))
```

Returns 0. Heck, even this returns 0:

```
=SUM(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A:A)),1,0))
```

Just for fun, I tried this one:

```
=SUM(IF(OR(TRUE(),ISBLANK(A:A)),1,0))
```

And it's 1 instead of 1048576. So whether you use AND or OR means it either returns 0 or 1 every time, respectively (I also tested the order of the cell reference in the OR and AND functions).

This seems like quite a flaw since other complicated formulas like this work as expected:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("MagicString",A:A)),1,0))
```

So, how do I use nontrivial conditional logic to count rows?

P.S. Using Office 2013

P.P.S. Automatic evaluation is disabled, and I made sure to press F9 to update the calculations.

Comment: You can't use **AND()** or **OR()** in an array-type formula.

Comment: To evaluate multiple conditions, try `SUMIFS` or, depending on how you need to evaluate the conditions, use `SUMPRODUCT` with multiplications and/or additions to do your **AND**ing and **OR**ing.  Using the `AND` or `OR` operators will only return a single result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use **AND()** or **OR()** in array-type formulas.  See:

[Previous Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130598/how-to-apply-a-logical-or-to-an-array-in-excel)

There are easy work-arounds using ***plus*** or ***multiply***